# Circumventing the same-origin policy with DNS trickery

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I'm writing a web app with Javascript which needs to access a third-party API (located on `x.apisite.com` and `y.apisite.com`). I was using `XMLHTTPRequest`, but when serving the files from my own local server, this fails because of the same-origin policy.

Now, this web app is supposed to be installed on my mobile device, where any downloaded files will be cached. So, I changed my DNS entries to point `x.apisite.com` and `y.apisite.com` to my own local server. I then download the files and then change the DNS entries back to the correct ones. I thought that since the browser thinks that the scripts were downloaded from `*.apisite.com`, I could now make `XMLHTTPRequest`s to `*.apisite.com`. However, this does not seem to be the case, I still get same-origin policy errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- this will actually be downloaded from my own local server -->
        <script src="http://x.apisite.com/script-0.js">
        <script src="http://y.apisite.com/script-1.js">
...
```

In `script-0.js`, I make an `XMLHTTPRequest` to `x.apisite.com`, and likewise in `script-1.js`, I access `y.apisite.com`.

Comment: "*I thought that since the browser thinks that the scripts were downloaded from `*.apisite.com`, I could now make `XMLHTTPRequests` to `*.apisite.com`.*" -- The origin of a client-side script has no bearing on same-origin rules. The source origin in SOP terms is always the origin of the *actual page* that loads the scripts and performs some action. You might be able to get away with DNS trickery, but you'll need to trick the browser into thinking the HTML page itself is from `apisite.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Practical answer (not recommended):  Create CNAME records to the third-party domains from domains that you control, then use those domains and hope that the hosts of the third-party aren't looking at the HTTP Host header.  Note that this wouldn't work if the clients attempt to authenticate the third-party hosts either;  for example when using HTTPS (some client browsers may force the use of HTTPS in certain scenarios).

Ideal answer:  Ask the third-party to authorize requests made by code that came from your origin domain using CORS (some hosts already allow requests from code from any origin, you should check that).

Alternative:  If the third-party doesn't want to give clients the go-ahead to make cross-origin requests with code from your domain, then you have to make those requests yourself (from your server).  The code you send to the client browsers will then only interact with the same origin, but this also means that users will have to trust you with their credentials if you're proxying requests for them (if that's relevant), or you must have credentials of your own to authenticate your server to the third-party hosts, which allow you to do whatever it is you want to do there.  It also means you take the traffic load as well, which may or may not be heavy depending on the application.  There are potentially many other implications, which all derive from the fact that you explicitly take responsibility for these requests.

Note:  While this may sound a bit complicated, it may be useful to understand the trust mechanics between the user, the user's client browser, the code executing in the browser, the origin of that code, and the domains to which that code makes requests.  Always keep in mind the best interests of each party in mind and it'll be easy to find a solution for your specific problem.

Final answer (everybody hates it, but you probably expected it):  "It depends on what exactly you're trying to do." (Sorry.)